# Remove one of the 2 Ubuntu 12.04 installed

Tags: 12.04

I installed a second ubuntu-12.04 LTS because the first one didn't work. They have the same name. Now I want remove the one that doesn't work. Using the file explorer I can mount, format and unmount the "device" with the pop-up menu (it is taken as a device by the system that works well). Running Format do I free the space occupied (127 GB)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

1.Boot to the "working" Ubuntu 12.04

2.Format the "broken" Ubuntu 12.04

3.Run this command:

```
sudo update-grub
```

4.Type password if prompt, its okay that you could not see what you are typing

5.Press Enter then Reboot or Restart the computer